# How to make a loop pull values from another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to create a loop that pulls values from another sheet in the workbook.

```
For i = 3 To 1000

    Worksheets("Cable Estimate").Select

    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then

        If Equipment = "Station Service Transformer" Then Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A2:D9").Copy Worksheets("Cable Estimate").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4))

        Exit For

        If Equipment = "13kV PTs (3 phase)" Then Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A11:D15").Copy Worksheets("Cable Estimate").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4))

        Exit For

        If Equipment = "13kV Tie Breaker" Then Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A18:D26").Copy Worksheets("Cable Estimate").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4))

        Exit For

     End If

Next i
```

The "Equipment" variable is set to equal a combo box value which is a list of material populated from another sheet. The exit for is listed under each piece of equipment such that the command only pulls the data from the other worksheet once.

When "Station Service Transformer" is selected (the first value in the combobox) the code pulls correctly into my sheet, however the code does not pull correctly any of the following equipment below that one. I believe I'm missing something either before or after each "exit for" statement. I also believe it may need some extra code like an "else if" if the cell value is not blank as in the first condition `If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then`.

Sidenote: I made the formula work by creating a separate `for i = 3 to 1000` and placing an "exit for" and "end if"  for each piece of equipment but I was hoping to make it all work under one "i".

Comment: It will never get to the second `If` because you have an `Exit For`. Restructure using If-Else and get rid of the Exit statements.

Comment: Also, don't do the `.select` in the loop, or at all just do `Worksheets("Cable Estimate").cells(I,1)` and leave  `Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A2:D9").Copy` as you are referencing the sheets.   Also, what is `Equipment` is this what is in `Worksheets("Cable Estimate").cells(I,1)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. i see how the exit for doesn't allow the function to run to the subsequent "ifs". My question is this: how can i get the function to run only once without the "exit for" but still read the subsequent ifs if necessary? If I don't have the "exit for", the function pastes the values in all cells up to 1000....

Comment: You don't need to copy at all if you just want the values to be the same. Set a target range and then `Target.Value = Source.Value`

Comment: The "Equipment" variable is set to equal a combo box value which is a list of material populated from another sheet.

Comment: Seems to me that the only value that anything is ever accomplished is the first time `Cells(i,1).Value = ""` and then nothing else. If there are multiple cases where you want to populate based on any cell being `""` in the 1st column your code does not do that. I would also suggest that you use an `If/End If` block instead of single lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as suggested above. Note too the full qualification of all ranges.

Your copy and paste ranges don't make much sense though. The ranges being copied are several rows long so you may end up overwriting cells when you paste.

Lastly, if `Equipment` doesn't change value, you could take it out of the loop and shorten the code.

```
With Worksheets("Cable Estimate")
    For i = 3 To 1000
        If .Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
            If Equipment = "Station Service Transformer" Then
                Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A2:D9").Copy .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 4))
            ElseIf Equipment = "13kV PTs (3 phase)" Then
                Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A11:D15").Copy .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 4))
            ElseIf Equipment = "13kV Tie Breaker" Then
                Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A18:D26").Copy .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 4))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

---

Revised in light of new requirements

```
Dim r As Range

With Worksheets("Cable Estimate")
    On Error GoTo 0 'avoid error if there are no blanks
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(1000, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1)
    On Error Resume Next
End With
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    If Equipment = "Station Service Transformer" Then
        Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A2:D9").Copy r
    ElseIf Equipment = "13kV PTs (3 phase)" Then
        Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A11:D15").Copy r
    ElseIf Equipment = "13kV Tie Breaker" Then
        Worksheets("Equipment List").Range("A18:D26").Copy r
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! The use of the "elseif" did solve the problem of the subsequent pieces of equipment below the original "if" not working, however, i need the function to exit after one paste. In the formula you posted above, the function re-pastes the equipment for all 1000 cells, when I need it to paste only once. Do you have a solution to this? I need to somehow insert an "exit for" function in there for each one....

Comment: I see. So in other words you want to find the first empty cell in column A and paste there?

Comment: Basically. But what i'm saying is the function currently (as you have it written) pastes  (for example, if "station service transformer" is selected) cells A2:D9 from the other worksheet over and over again through cell 1000. I need it to only paste once.

Comment: I think that works pretty well. Thanks for your help